# Half of our Azure web role instances are not saving IIS logs to blob storage

Tags: azure, logging, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-roles

We are trying to save our IIS logs to blob storage in Azure. We have 8 web role instances. It looks like we are only getting the last 4 instances' logs.

Looking at the folder structure in blob storage it appears that I have logs for instance 4 to 7 but none for 0 to 3.

This is odd as the 8 instances are running the same code.

Comment: what is the chance that 0 to 3 instances are not being hit but requests, so they don't generate any IIS logs ? Do you have some other tracing events logged, showing that there is real activity on those instances ?

Comment: Azure should round robin requests to all the web servers. We also record asp.net Applications(__Total__)\Requests/Sec and there is activity on all web servers.

Answer (score 0):

You should confirm that all instances have same diagnostics configuration.  Instances can have different settings if you set instances once and then scaled up for example (very common).  You can do this by manually comparing the files located in the wad-control-container of your Diagnostics account and ensuring that the missing instances are actually transferring data.  Alternatively, you can use the Windows Azure MMC and inspect the settings by instance.

Comment: I think I see the problem. This is from one of the instances that is not saving iis-logs.       <BufferQuotaInMB>0</BufferQuotaInMB>
      <ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>0</ScheduledTransferPeriodInMinutes>  so now how do I change this?